# Refresh field's value periodicly with a background thread

Tags: python, django, django-models

First of all , the title is not 100% accurate since I don't really mind if the solution is going to be with a thread or not.

In my django project I have a model with some fields . One of the fields is calculated by a function . So in my *models.py* it looks like that :

```py
class Feed(models.Model):

    name = models.ForeignKey(Name, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)

    def set_status(self, _status=None):
        # code that i have to implement
        if status is None:
            return 'ACTIVE'
        else:
            return _status
    status = property(set_status)
```

What I am trying to do is to be able to re-set the value of the status field periodically and after that to refresh the page so that the user will have the updated status.
My main idea was to somehow call a background thread that it is going to wait for a socket message , something like:

```py
def wait_for_status_change(self):
    #setting the socket
    while True:
        # socket wait to receive and edit the message accordingly
        self.set_status(socket_message)
```

Obviously I will have to specify in what specific object of this model I want to change the status field .
I tried to use Celery , but I think it is too complicated for the cause so I would not like to use it for that problem.

I also thought of a solution with a scheduler but I did't really understood how to use it in that case.

I know that there are some things that I misunderstood , and maybe I am not thinking it in the right way ,so I would appreciate any advice, to any direction.

EDIT:
I tried using Django-q schedulers but I couldn't make it work. 
In the documentation is mentioned :

> You can manage them through the Admin pages or directly from your code .

so I added this code in my *admin.py*:

```py
    if schedule('Feed.set_status', 'not active', schedule_type='I', minutes=1, repeats=-1, next_run=datetime.now()):
        print('SCHEDULED')
```

And added some print() in my function so that I can check if it is indeed called. 
When I runserver i get the "scheduled" message but it doesn't seem like it is actually calling the function again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Celery is indeed big for this task, but I'd go with a library anyway. I'd try with [django-q](https://django-q.readthedocs.io/). It has [schedulers](https://django-q.readthedocs.io/en/latest/schedules.html) and it is possible to use it without external dependencies (using the Django ORM as a message broker, instead of other tools like Redis). It has other advantages, such that we can see the tasks in the Django admin.

The doc mentions the possibility to schedule Django management commands. So that could be another possibility actually: you write a management command that does the update of your field, and you setup a cron job either with a one-time system command, either in python with a [cron library](https://pypi.org/search/?q=cron) (no preferences there for me).

A django-q scheduler is easy to setup, it looks like this:

```py
from django_q.models import Schedule

Schedule.objects.create(func='math.copysign',
                        hook='hooks.print_result',
                        args='2,-2',
                        schedule_type=Schedule.DAILY
                        )
```

We can schedule more precisely: `next_run=arrow.utcnow().replace(hour=18, minute=0)`.

Other lightweight task queues include [Huey](http://huey.readthedocs.io/) (needs redis) and [others](https://djangopackages.org/search/?q=task).

Comment: Django-q schedulers looks like a really good fit indeed but I cannot make it work , please check my EDIT in my question.

Comment: Your configuration looks fine… maybe you forgot to start the async process ? (read `configuration` carefully). Then you might as well ask on the project page or on another issue :/